# How can I join records where all of right table must be in set?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a table **products**.

Product has many **features** through **product_features**.

I want to return all, and *only* the products that have both feature 1, and feature 2, so a typical LEFT JOIN won't work in this case—since that would return the **products** that have *either* feature 1 or feature 2.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use two inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inner join ,  group by  and having

```
select p.* from products as p 
inner join product_features as pf on pf.product_id = p.id
inner join features as f on f.id = pf.feature_id 
where f.feature_id in ('feature1', 'feature2') 
group by product 
having count(*) =2;
```

the answwr is based on the fact that the featurs in set are present only one time

Comment: This assumes that features '1' and '2' will each have only a single product_features record for a given product.  This is probably the case, but you should confirm that.

Comment: @PinnyM  the query should work for all the products with both   ('feature1', 'feature2')  ..

Comment: Yes it will, however it will also return entries (incorrectly) where feature '1' has 2 records and feature '1' has no records.  You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT pf.feature_id) = 2` to get around this.

Comment: @PinnyM  yes..  of couurse .. but this is not in the question .. and i  assume that the features are properly distributed ... could be the OP comment properly ..

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything :)  However, I did mention above that it was probably the case as you are expecting it.

Comment: Anyway i have update the asnwer mentioning the problem related to the fact of the features present one time only

Answer (score 0):

Through OLAP functions, you can achieve this.
The below query counts distinct features of each product. It returns all products which has two features.

```
select pid, pname, fid
from (
  select t1.pid, t1.pname,t2.fid,count(distinct fid) over(partition by t1.pid, t1.pname) cnt from 
  products t1 left join product_features t2
  on t1.pid = t2.pid
) a
where cnt = 2
order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for products matching two _specific_ features, not two of any features

Comment: Its good if he can provide some sample data on what output he is expecting